# Automatically generating YouTube embed using basic URL with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe, youtube

When I paste a video URL into a blog post, I want it to appear as an iframe embedded player with custom parameters using the YouTube API. When I embed a video I don't want to have to add the parameters manually each time. Here is my JS:

```
$('body').html(function(i, html) {
return html.replace(/(?:http:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?(?:youtube\.com|youtu\.be)\/(?:watch\?v=)?(.+)/g, '<center><iframe width="640" height="360" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/$1?modestbranding=1&rel=0&wmode=transparent&theme=light&color=white" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe></center>').replace(/(?:http:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?(?:vimeo\.com)\/(.+)/g, '<center><iframe src="//player.vimeo.com/video/$1" width="640" height="360" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe></center>').replace(/(?:http:\/\/)?(?:dailymotion\.com|dai\.ly)\/(.+)/g, '<center><iframe frameborder="0" width="560" height="315" src="http://www.dailymotion.com/embed/video/$1?logo=0&foreground=ffffff&highlight=1bb4c6&background=000000" allowfullscreen></iframe></center>');
});
```

[Here is a JSfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/88Ms2/341/)

But when I transfer it to my website on Blogger, it doesn't work ([example](http://www.freedomrequireswings.com/2013/07/glee.html#HTML9)).

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: I want to do this so I can add parameters to the embed URL. I know how to embed a video, but I don't want to have to add the parameters manually each time.

Comment: Why it doesn't work on your site? Do you get any errors? Looking at the link I can see an article with embedded YouTube video

Comment: When you click "Play" there's an error and when you click the "YouTube" icon in the bottom right-hand corner it brings you to [www.youtube.com/?](http://www.youtube.com/?)

Answer (score 2):

Try with this:

```
$('body').html(function(i, html) {
return html.replace(/(?:http:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?(?:youtube\.com|youtu\.be)\/(?:watch\?v=)?([^<]+)/g, '<center><iframe width="640" height="360" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/$1?modestbranding=1&rel=0&wmode=transparent&theme=light&color=white" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe></center>').replace(/(?:http:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?(?:vimeo\.com)\/([^<]+)/g, '<center><iframe src="//player.vimeo.com/video/$1" width="640" height="360" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe></center>').replace(/(?:http:\/\/)?(?:dailymotion\.com|dai\.ly)\/([^<]+)/g, '<center><iframe frameborder="0" width="560" height="315" src="http://www.dailymotion.com/embed/video/$1?logo=0&foreground=ffffff&highlight=1bb4c6&background=000000" allowfullscreen></iframe></center>');
});
```

You have `</div>` after media link, so you need to stop match before less-than.

Check [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/88Ms2/342/).

Comment: However, this code also changes the sources of existing iframes, causing them to appear as errors. Is there any modification we could make to the code so this doesn't happen? There are over 450 posts on my site and I don't want to have to replace all the video embeds with basic links.

Comment: It's just regexp tweak, so if you provide link snippets (link and wrapper) on that other posts, we can tweak regexp to match what you need :)

Comment: I don't understand. Wouldn't it be easier to detect the date of the posts on the blog using javascript and apply the above script if the post date is after 20th February 2014?

Comment: Could I use javascript to detect the date of the post http://www.threelas.com/2012/05/how-to-retrieve-posts-using-blogger.html and if that date is after 20 February 2014, then it could run the code to replace the YouTube url?

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use the oEmbed protocol, I think it does exactlyy what you need: check out http://oembed.com/

From the documentation:

> oEmbed is a format for allowing an embedded representation of a URL on third party sites. The simple API allows a website to display embedded content (such as photos or videos) when a user posts a link to that resource, without having to parse the resource directly.

I saw that the three video providers you used in your example have an oEmbed API:

- Vimeo: http://developer.vimeo.com/apis/oembed
- Dailymotion: http://www.dailymotion.com/doc/api/oembed.html
- Youtube: I can't find the link but i'm pretty sure they also support oEmbed

Answer (score 0):

Just a small regex-tweak: Added 'https'-case which applies most of the time now and some more ways to detect the url ended, mainly for the case the url is not in an enclosing tag, but in running text.

```
return html.replace(/(?:http:|https:)?(?:\/\/)(?:www\.)?(?:youtube\.com|youtu\.be)\/(?:watch\?v=)?([^<.,!():"'\s]+)/g, '<iframe width="600" height="350" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/$1?modestbranding=1&rel=0&wmode=transparent&theme=light&color=white" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>').replace(/(?:http:|https:)?(?:\/\/)(?:www\.)?(?:vimeo\.com)\/([^<.,!():"'\s]+)/g, '<iframe src="//player.vimeo.com/video/$1" width="600" height="350" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>').replace(/(?:http:|https:)?(?:\/\/)(?:dailymotion\.com|dai\.ly)\/([^<.,!():"'\s]+)/g, '<iframe frameborder="0" width="600" height="350" src="http://www.dailymotion.com/embed/video/$1?logo=0&foreground=ffffff&highlight=1bb4c6&background=000000" allowfullscreen></iframe>');
```